# Find the user logged in to application how many times with different version

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle table which has record of frequent logins with different versions of applications. for Version_1 there is one entry but for Version_2 there are 8 entries.  These 8 entries are having different time stamps(different milli sec). I want to find out for each user howmany times he is logging in to the Version_2 application. Here we can take Minutes to remove duplicate records.

Here is the sample data with column names

[image: Employee Login details]

I want to find out the each user has logged in how many time excluding the duplicate entry(these entries have different time stamps with change in milli seconds).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT count(emp_id) as log_number,app_version FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE
app_version like 'VER_2';
```